# Data Extension Extract using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-extract, tracking-extract

I would like to execute a Data Extension extract using API. Went through the below documentation but it asks for Start and End Date which doesn't make sense for Data Extension extract. Any suggestions?

[Data Extension Extract](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api/)

Comment: Any suggestions experts ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but in case you haven't already solved this.

[Retrieveing data from a Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)

The below sample includes a 'filter' to a specific email address, which is not necessary, but I would highly recommend a filter, especially on larger DEs to ensure your call does not time out or butt up on the 2500 record limit of API calls. (This can be solved, if necessary, via a [DO/WHILE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp) and ContinueRequest - sample SOAP: `<ContinueRequest>requestID</ContinueRequest>` based on the [MoreDataAvailable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve.htm?search_text=continue%20request) status)

Sample SOAP envelope from the documentation:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <RetrieveRequest>
 <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Example DE]</ObjectType>
 <Properties>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Properties>
 <Properties>CUSTOMER_ID</Properties>
 <Properties>FIRST_NAME</Properties>
 <Properties>SITE_GROUP</Properties>
 <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
 <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
 <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
 <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
 </Filter>
 </RetrieveRequest>
 </RetrieveRequestMsg>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Optional Filter Part of the above call:

```
<Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
 <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
 <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
 <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
 </Filter>
```